# Initialization with parameters

Tags: c++, audio, sdl, objectinstantiation

I am following this tutorial on audio programming in C++ an theres is something I do not understand; what does the fourth line suppose to represent? I understand I am not creating an instance of AudioObject because I do not instantiate it with the new keyword. However why can assign attributes to it? This closely resembles a function declaration which gets me confused as sound is a used as reference elsewhere in my main. e.g

```
SampleInfo info; //struct
info.volume = 1.0;

AudioObject sound(info, data); //<--this line


//why can assign info, data
```

Comment: Read up on the "Most Vexing Parse": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: @AlexZywicki It's a good read indeed, but there is no most vexing parse here though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in fact creating an instance of an `AudioObject` with [automatic storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) , but not a dynamically allocated instance (via `new`). `info` and `data` are the arguments you pass to the constructor. Avoid using `new` except when you really need it, C++ is not Java.